# Tomcat 8.0.33 Crashed due to APR in a Virtual Machine

Tags: java, tomcat8, apr

We have application deployed on tomcat & its working good for most of the customer, but recently we installed it for two customers on a virtual machine & it looks like tomcat is crashing after few days.

Machine Details:
It is a Virtual Machine
[image: Windows Server 2012 R2, 64-bit, 8GB RAM, Intel Xeon E5-2665 dual processor @2.4GHz]

Both the server crashed with almost exact same crash log.

=====================================

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x23a56eb6, pid=3084, tid=5852
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_77-b03) (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (25.77-b03 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [tcnative-1.dll+0x6eb6]
```

=====================================

```
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 6544  org.apache.tomcat.jni.Poll.poll(JJ[JZ)I (0 bytes) @ 0x014aacd0 [0x014aac60+0x70]
J 8272% C2 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Poller.run()V (2267 bytes) @ 0x021c140c [0x021c11c0+0x24c]
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

=====================================

From my research on Google & if I am reading this crash logs correctly it seems to me like the tomcat crashed on "org.apache.tomcat.jni.Poll.poll" class when used from "org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Poller.run()" thread.

And this exception meaning is: somewhere native code tried to write on a memory and it failed.

These are my temporary solution suggestions for now:

1. Upgrade tomcat to 8.0.47. Looks like some bug-fixes talk about APR issues.
2. Upgrade APR to latest available.
3. Disable APR by removing the .dll file.

Since I don't have the root cause m not confident on any of above solutions.

Please do correct me if I am wrong in my analysis up till now.

We are trying to find root cause of this issue. Can anyone help us with it?

Let me know if it needs full crash log or memory dump to analyze further.

Comment: You likely have the wrong native thread.

Comment: I spoke to tomcat dev support team, and it looks like a bug which was fixed in latest version, so we upgraded tomcat to 8.0.47 & issue didnt occur again.